# Changing number of values on a field in installation profile

Tags: entities, installation

I am creating an installation profile with multiple fields. For a 'file' field I want to change the number of values. I have two questions about this.

Is this an field setting or an instance setting?
and what is the right way of changing this setting I tried these:

```
'number_values' => '2',
'max_value' => '2',
'max_values' => '2',
'values' => '2',
'value' => '2',
```

I can't find any of this on the internet. Any help and tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a field setting (`cardinality`), so assuming you're using [`field_create_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) to create it...

```
$field = array(
  'entity_types' => array('node'),
  'cardinality' => 2,
  'translatable' => FALSE,
  'locked' => FALSE,
  // etc...
);
field_create_field($field);
```

For unlimited values you can use the [`FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/constant/FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED/7) constant.